# What does this line mean in Makefile?

Tags: python-3.x, makefile

Here is the target from the Makefile:

```
env: $(ROOT)/deps/vunit/setup.py
$(ROOT)/deps/vunit/setup.py:
    virtualenv virtualenv
    rm -rf deps
    mkdir deps -p
    git clone http://work-bitbucket/scm/vhdlos/vunit.git deps/vunit --recurse-submodules
    cd deps/vunit && git checkout origin/dev
    source ./virtualenv/Scripts/activate && \
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -e deps/vunit
```

The `$(ROOT)/deps/vunit/setup.py` appears just after `env` and then again just below it. What could this mean? The VUnit is a Python package.

Answer (score 2):

The general form of a Makefile is a sequence of

```
target: prerequisites
    optional recipe
    more optional recipe lines
```

This means, to build `target`, first you have to build `prerequisites`. Once those are in place, execute the commands `optional recipe` and `more optional recipe lines`. If these succeed, as a result, `target` will have been created.

So, your `Makefile` fragment states that in order to create `env`, you need to create `$(ROOT)/deps/vunit/setup.py`; it then explains how to create this file, with no additional prerequisites.

The last three lines are joined by backslashes because these commands need to be executed in the same shell. Briefly, each command is executed in a separate subshell; `activate` on a line of its own would spawn a new shell, run `activate` in it, and then exit that shell, losing any changes which the `activate` command made in the shell's environment.

(Probably `env` is not an actual file name, and should be declared as `.PHONY:`)

Answer (score 1):

The first line 'env: $(ROOT)/...' define a make target 'env' that can be use by the user to trigger building of the '.../setup.py' file.

Basically `make env` is equivalent to `make $(ROOT)/deps/vunit/setup.py`, with the appropriate substitution for the ROOT variable. Without the `env` target, invoking the build on setup.py requires knowledge of the actual values of ROOT.

```
make env
```